# sonar lint plugin fails reading lint-results.xml

Tags: android, sonarqube, lint

I have an gradle android build using android build tools version 1.3.1 and run lint checks on my code. When running the sonar task (provided by the org.sonarqube gradle plugin) the sonar lint plugin (org.sonar.plugins.android.lint.AndroidLintSensor) fails when reading the lint-result file with the following error:

```
2:35:44.278 [Daemon worker] ERROR o.s.p.a.lint.AndroidLintProcessor - Exception reading /Users/Rene/dev/gradleware/clients/bosch/trials/MyAndroidApplication/app/build/outputs/lint-results-freeRelease-fatal.xml
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(inline=true, entry=, name=, data=false, empty=true, required=true, type=void) on field 'issues' java.util.List org.sonar.plugins.android.lint.AndroidLintProcessor$LintIssues.issues for class org.sonar.plugins.android.lint.AndroidLintProcessor$LintIssues at line 2
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.validate(Composite.java:644) ~[simple-xml-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:449) ~[simple-xml-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59) ~[simple-xml-2.7.1.jar:na]
```

The lint xml itself looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<issues format="4" by="lint 24.1.2">

</issues>
```

I'm using sonarqube 5.2 with android sonar plugin 1.1 installed. Is this a known issue? or is there a workaround available?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue, see my answer.

Comment: thanks. I'll track this issue.

Comment: is there a way to get a nightly version of the plugin into my local sonar installation to test the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in android lint sonar plugin 1.1, see the ticket associated with this issue : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARANDRO-38

This should be fixed in version 1.2 of the sonar android lint plugin.

Comment: I am using SonarQube version 5,4 and facing the same error. The problem is that after installing "Lint" from the web interface, the only version available is 1.1 and not 1.2. Do you know a workaround to use 1.2 ?

Comment: A bit late, but the plugin is no longer officially maintained. Nevertheless you can download the code and build it by yourself. Or do you have an alternative, @WahibUlHaq?